# Regex to remove the first 2 lines of a text file

Tags: regex

I am trying to delete only the first 2 lines of a text file.

I tried using `\A.*`, but this gets the first line and deletes the rest.

Is there a way to do the inverse?

Comment: Regex is not the best answer here.

Comment: if there is a regex that allows you to get the text file starting from the second line, that will work also.

Answer (score 3):

It is maybe not the most convenient way, but it is possible with Regex:

```
^.*\n.*\n([\s\S]*)$
```

With default settings (neither single-line nor multi-line modifiers) the '.' captures everything, except newline. Therfore, `.*\n` captures one line, including the new line character. Repeat it twice, and we are at the beginning of the third line. Now capture all characters, including the new line character (`[\s\S]` is a nice workaround for this behavior) until the end of the file `$`.

Then substitute by the first capturing group

```
\1
```

and you have everything but the first 2 lines.

The details depend on your regex engine, how you give the substitute string. And depending on the platform or the used new line character of the file, you might need to exchange the `\n` with `\r\n` or `\r` or the one that matches it all `(\r\n?|\n)`.

Here is a working [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK7vE8/1).